# Как получить координаты вектора?

Tags: javascript, геометрия, вектор, линейная-алгебра

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как мне определить координаты **х2** и **у2** вектора **B**, если мне известна вся информация о них, включая их длину? Или в какой раздел обратиться и изучить?

Comment: Обратиться в раздел скалярного произведения векторов.

Comment: Начальный точки совпадают? (Bx1=Ax1?)

Comment: @MBo, да, совпадают

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Берём точку, находящуюся на расстоянии `BLength` от базовой точки и поворачиваем её на нужный угол.

```
xx = Ax1 + (Ax2 - Ax1) * BLength / ALength
yy = Ay1 + (Ay2 - Ay1) * BLength / ALength

Bx2 = Ax1 + (xx - Ax1) * Cos(Fi) - (yy - Ay1) * Sin(Fi)
By2 = Ay1 + (xx - Ax1) * Sin(Fi) + (yy - Ay1) * Cos(Fi)
```

Пример:

```
 Ax1,Ay1=0; Ax2=3, Ay2=0, Fi=Pi/4, ALength = 3, BLength = 2
 xx = 0 + 3 * 2 / 3 = 2
 yy = 0 + 0 = 0
 bx2 = 2 * 0.707 = 1.414
 by2 = 2 * 0.707 = 1.414
```

Comment: Угол в этом случае это `Fi`? И если да в `rad` или `deg`?

Comment: Да, Fi. [Радианы](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/sin)

Comment: В результате получается вектор между этими двумя и длинее

Comment: Между какими двумя, если дан только один? Наверное, кто-то что-то неправильно посчитал.